# Node Google Geocoder Callback Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, google-geocoder

Here's what I'm working with:
getLocation('123 Foobar Ln');

```
function getLocation(location) {
  console.log(location); // prints 123 Foobar Ln
  getLocationData(location, function(gotLocation) {
    console.log('hello?'); // this doesn't print
    return gotLocation;
  });
}

function getLocationData(location, callback) {
  geocoder.geocode(location, function(err, res) {
    if (res[0] != undefined) {
      geoaddress = (res[0].formattedAddress);
      addressmessage = 'Formatted Address: ' + geoaddress;
      callback(addressmessage);

    } else {
      geocoder.geocode(cleanedAddress, function(err, res) {
        addressmessage = 'null';
        if (res[0] != undefined) {
          geoaddress = (res[0].formattedAddress);
          addressmessage = 'Formatted Address: ' + geoaddress;
          callback(addressmessage);
        } else {
          addressmessage = 'Address could not be found: ' + location;
          callback(addressmessage);

        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I'm struggling to have getLocation do anything with the callback from getLocationData.

The only ouput I get when I run the following is: `123 Foobar Ln`

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you never call it though. you just set it equal to that string.

Comment: Fixed that by using `callback(addressmessage) but it's still not returning anything =/

Comment: first off the `geocode` methods are aysnc, so you're calling your callback before they're complete. move it to the bottom of the callback fuction in each. Also, you're not using your error params. In future, below each function with an error param print the error if it exists to get some insight. `if(err){console.log('geocode error', err);}`, `if(err){console.log('geocode clean error', err);}`

Comment: also you have a syntax error: on the second to last line, get rid of the `})`.

Comment: i may have been wrong about that syntax error. either that or the code changed while i was tinkering with it in another screen. i've edited to be so those braces are right now. But you're still not checking for errors though. that will be your quickest way to find out if something critical is going wrong.

Comment: did you add the error checks?

Comment: yeah. got it to work; I can console.log in the callback function - return doesn't work, now I just need to figure out how to get the "formattedAddress" out of this so I can use this elsewhere. The only thing that works for me right now is using res.render and passing it in to a template but I need to store the address as a variable (is return supposed to work in the callback function?)

Comment: Whatever calls `getLocation` will have its value set to `getLocation`'s `return` value. So you can do something like `var getLocationResponse = getLocation(location);` and then do whatever you like with the `getLocationResponse` variable. It will contain the returned value.

Comment: Did the solution I posted work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error that is tripping you up most here is that you are searching for index `0` of `res` and `res` is an object. Now that your callback use is fixed, that's the only remaining problem, other than

1. `cleanedaddress` isn't defined, but I just take it for granted that it must be somewhere higher up in your code.
2. `123 Foobar Lane` is an address that is likely nonexistent, but maybe you just used that for the post.

A simplified working version:

```
var geocoder = require('google-geocoding');
//https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-geocoding

function getLocation(location) {
  getLocationData(location, function(latLong) {
    console.log('latLong:', latLong);
  });
}

function getLocationData(location, callback) {
  geocoder.geocode(location, function(err, res) {
    if (err){
      console.log('geocode error', err);
    }else{
      callback(res);
    }
  });
}

getLocation('1060 W Addison St, Chicago, IL 60613');

// => latLong: { lat: 41.9474536, lng: -87.6561341 }
```

Hope this helps.